# Using Windows Forms to open a browser and call a Javascript function

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I'm new to this so please bear with me.  I am using a VB.NET (2.0) Windows Forms application.

On Form_Load(), I open up IE browser, which then navigates to a particular URL with a login form.  It passes the u/n and p/w values to this form and gets the button id and calls the click function on it, causing the browser to redirect to the web site as a user.  It then executes a script on that page, which displays a bulk upload control.

I want to be able to get/set the value in the text box on this page.

'-->>> **theTextBox = Nothing**.  After executing the script, the bulk update div is 'created in the page by the script.  If we do a View Source, we can see an element with ID as 'TXT_UPLOAD as below.
'INPUT type="TEXT" id="TXT_UPLOAD" size="78" onblur="checkFileType(this,this.value, 'true)"
Here is my code:

```
Dim IE As New Object

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load


    Dim URL As String = "http://someurl.com/"

    Try

        IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
        IE.Visible = True
        IE.Navigate("https://someurl.com/Login.aspx?")

        Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)

        WaitUntil(IE.Document)


        IE.Document.getElementById("tb_login").value = "username"
        IE.Document.getElementById("tb_password").value = "password"

        Dim theButton
        theButton = IE.Document.getElementById("btn_login")
        theButton.Click()

        Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
        WaitUntil(IE.Document)

        IE.Document.parentWindow.execScript("parent.showApplication('Bulk Update', 712030600,-1,712000000,1);")



        Dim theTextBox
        theTextBox = IE.Document.getElementById("TXT_UPLOAD")
        theTextBox.Focus()
        Debug.Print(theTextBox.value)
        theTextBox.Value = "C:\NV\CV\CLWR_NA_CHG_UPLOAD_2014313.csv"


       IE.Document.parentWindow.execScript("parent.logOff();")


    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)

        Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
        WaitUntil(IE.Document)
        IE.Document.parentWindow.execScript("parent.logOff();")

    End Try

    IE = Nothing

    'IE.kill()

    'IE.Quit()


    End
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: Getting an SystemNullReferenceException: Object variable or With block variable not set at the line -- theTextBox = IE.Document.getElementById("TXT_UPLOAD")

Comment: Try changing to this `Dim theTextBox As IHTMLElement` and then `Set theTextBox = IE.Document.getElementById("TXT_UPLOAD")` and see if the error moves!